# hybridauth's social_hub/login.php doesn't work

Tags: hybridauth

I install the hybridauth on windows IIS, and setup the hybridauth\config.php as below:
    array(
        "base_url" => "http:///hybridauth/",

```
    "providers" => array ( 
                  .....
        "Google" => array ( 
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "<myappkey>", "secret" => "<myappsecret>" ), 
            "scope"   => "email"
        ),
             )
```

But when I click "Sign-in with Google" in http:///examples/social_hub/login.php, it just redirect me to http:///hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1401608000 which show the files under "localhost - /hybridauth/"
Anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1) i am not sure if your scope is properly set up (you should have probably set it to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

2) did you set up the return address in google api correct?